# Word for a clarification/exception

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a document with a table including a general statement like 'software supports files of type X.' However, there are certain cases where I do not support it yet and/or I'm not sure. I want to add a link to a section describing the specific things I don't handle currently. There is a word for these kinds of exceptions that I cannot think of.

Words I'm not thinking of but looked at thesaurus hoping to find this word:

- exception
- clarification
- disclaimer

Comment: consider "particular cases".

Comment: Thanks @Graffito but I'm sure its a single word, and I feel its either a technical term or perhaps more of a legal term.

Comment: if "Addendum" is not specific enough: "Excursus" ?

Comment: Addendum is too general and not really the point, this is specifically about exceptions to a statement or exclusionary conditions. I've never heard of excursus and is also similar to addendum. Nothing specifying that this is appended or an after thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were you thinking of caveat ?

**Caveat** (n):

a. A warning or caution: made a recommendation with many caveats.

b. A qualification or explanation.

[caveat@thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/caveat)

Comment: That matches exactly what I was thinking, but oddly I don't think it is the word I was trying to remember. I like caveat so I'll go with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The word **Errata** holds some similarities with what you've described.

> A list of errors and their corrections inserted, usually on a separate page or slip of paper, in a book or other publication;

*[www.dictionary.com/browse/errata](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/errata)*

Admittedly, the definition doesn't seem like a perfect fit, but I've seen it  used (incorrectly?) in semi-formal technical documentation similarly to what you're describing. So just throwing it out there.

Comment: Thanks, great suggestion. Not what I'm looking for though.